# node.js - how do i actually get request?

Tags: ajax, node.js

I'm asking a lot questions lately ;)

So I made some progress in creating my web chat. 

So I got it to work, 
My question was, How to type something into the textarea, and after click enter the message will be logged into the server?

I updated the code, so it works.

The node.js file -

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var messages = [];

// Simple Function to Load all of the HTML/CSS/JavaScript Files.
function LoadHTML(html, requrl, res) {
    var filePath = '.' + requrl;
    if (filePath == './') {
        filePath = './' + html;
    }

    var extname = path.extname(filePath);
    var contentType = 'text/html';
    switch (extname) {
        case '.js':
            contentType = 'text/javascript';
        break;
        case '.css':
            contentType = 'text/css';
        break;
    }

    fs.exists(filePath, function(exists) {

        if (exists) {
            fs.readFile(filePath, function(error, content) {
                if (error) {
                    res.writeHead(500);
                    res.end();
                }
                else {
                    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType });
                    res.end(content, 'utf-8');
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            res.writeHead(404);
            res.end();
        }  
    });  
}

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    var url = req.url;

    LoadHTML('index.html', url, res);

    if(url.substring(0,16) == "/ser.js?message=") {
        var message = url.substring(16, url.length);
        console.log(message);
    }

}).listen(8125);
```

Here is the HTML/CSS/JavaScript Code - http://jsfiddle.net/Q79PK/1/

**EDIT:** I got it to work, I updated the code, You can look and learn ;)
Up votes will be great!

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `http.get(options, callback)` as it is designed to perform a HTTP GET without data.
Instead use `http.request(options, callback)` in which you will be able to add data to the request. See: http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback

For server-side logging and handling data posted within the request, make the netire `req` object to be the parameter of the loadHTML function (and not `req.url`). Then you will be able to add a listener to the ServerRequest:

```
req.addListener("data", function(data) {
    console.log("data : "+data);
});
```

(and update `var filePath = '.' + req;` accordingly to `var filePath = '.' + req.url;` ).

You can test this by simulating the request using the cURL command if you have it :

```
curl -d "some data" http://localhost:8125
```

and server-side you have the following logging:

```
data : some data
```

Here is the full modifications of the code that I made :

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var messages = [];

// Simple Function to Load all of the HTML/CSS/JavaScript Files.
function LoadHTML(html, req, res) {
    var filePath = '.' + req.url;
    if (filePath == './') {
        filePath = './' + html;
    }

    req.addListener("data", function(data) {
        console.log("data : "+data);
    });

    var extname = path.extname(filePath);
    var contentType = 'text/html';
    switch (extname) {
        case '.js':
            contentType = 'text/javascript';
        break;
        case '.css':
            contentType = 'text/css';
        break;
    }

    fs.exists(filePath, function(exists) {

        if (exists) {
            fs.readFile(filePath, function(error, content) {
                if (error) {
                    res.writeHead(500);
                    res.end();
                }
                else {
                    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType });
                    res.end(content, 'utf-8');
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            res.writeHead(404);
            res.end();
        }  
    });  
}

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    LoadHTML('./index.html', req, res); // Calling the Function to load all of the files.
}).listen(8125);
```

HTH

Comment: It is not working.. when I type something into the textarea and click enter it log to my chrome console 404 (Not Found).

Comment: You may have also problem client-side. Try to validate you chain link by link. For server-side, undependently from client-side, can you manage to have to expected behavior by performing a curl command as follows : <code>curl -d "some data" http://localhost:8125</code> ? Once this works, you could then see what is happening client-side cause you will be sure server-side is OK.